# Angular element inside bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I am using Bootstrap with angular 2, My angular (click) is not working inside my popover content.

**HTML:**

```
 <p id="myPopover-profile">Operator</p>

    <div class="profile-option" id="profile-option">
      <div class="user-name"> Jhone Doe</div>
      <div class="line"> </div>
      <div class="end-session" (click)="endSession()"> End Session </div>
      <div class="logout"> Logout </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**TS:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    $('#myPopover-profile').popover({
      placement: 'bottom',
      toggle: 'popover',
      html: true,
      content:  function() {
        return $('#profile-option').html();
      }
    });

  }

  endSession(){
    console.log("test");
  }
```

Comment: Where is your html declared?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api

Comment: Nope nope nope. Stop. Stop using Angular AND jQuery. Use Angular OR jQuery, not both together. They are competitors and have completely different approaches. Angular generates the DOM, jQuery manipulates it. Do things the Angular way, OR the jQuery way. You're just mixing up stuff clumsily and loading two libraries instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you create a component for your popover and in the popover html you do something like `<my-component></my-component>` therefore you can use **myComponent.ts** file to have the logic you want.